# What is the rule for type deduction for assignment using brace initialization?

Tags: c++, c++20

In the following code, to my surprise, the `{ }` appears to create a default initialized instance of `int` rather than of `A`.

```
struct A {
  int i = 1;
  A() = default;
  A& operator=(const A& a) {
    this->i = a.i;
    return *this;
  }
  A& operator=(int i) {
    this->i = i;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a = { };
  return a.i;
}
```

What rule is used to parse `a = { }`? I thought that `a = { }` would have to be equivalent to `a = decltype(a){ }`.

What is the right term for the type of initialization that takes place here?

Here's an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/j8xsPYKb5) on godbolt. At `-O0` the assembly shows exactly which function is being used. Unless the `int` assignment operator is removed, `A::operator=(int)` is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the braced-init-list `{}` could be used to initialize both `int` and `A`, which are also considered as conversion, and the conversion from `{}` to `int` wins in overload resolution, since the conversion from `{}` to `A` (via `A::A()`) is considered as a user-defined conversion.

Assignment operator is not special, compilers just collect all the viable `operator=`s in overload set, then determine which one should be selected by overload resolution. If you add another `operator=(float)` you'll get an ambiguous error since conversion from `{}` to `int` and from `{}` to `float` are both considered as standard conversion with same rank, which wins against user-defined conversion.

Comment: This is totally bizarre. So, `{ }` will be an int as long the code compiles, kinda SFINAE style? I just checked, if I replace `A& operator=(int i)` with `A& operator=(float i)` this operator is still used! Or does the compiler attempt to use types collected from every viable assignment operator and then chooses the most trivial type?

Comment: @SU3 Think about `int i{}; float f{};`, they're just same as `A a{};`.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand how this works now. Adding both `operator=(int)` and  `operator=(float)` results in a compilation error: *ambiguous overload for 'operator='*. I just didn't know that the compiler looks at available assignment operators rather than just going for `decltype(a){ }`.

Comment: @SU3 Yes, this is how overload resolution works. `operator=(int)` and `operator=(float)` are in the same rank, they're both standard conversion, which wins against user-defined conversion.

Comment: @SU3 Compilers just collect all the viable `operator=`s, then judge them via overload resolution. There's no special rule for assignment operator.

Comment: If the `operator=` method was provided, what would it look like for a non-conversion `a = { };`, so would have first consideration before any of the conversions?

Comment: @Eljay Sorry I can't get your question. If `operator=` is provided as OP's code, then ...?

Comment: If the OP's code was changed to provide another `operator=`, which for the `{ }` part of `a = { };` would be a *non-conversion* assignment operator, what would that look like?  `A& operator=(/*what goes here?*/)` ... something like `std::initializer_list<int>`?

Comment: @Eljay Yes, if provide a `operator=` taking `std::initializer_list<int>`, it'll be perferred in [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution). *A list-initialization sequence L1 is better than list-initialization sequence L2 if L1 initializes an std::initializer_list parameter, while L2 does not.*

Comment: To clarify, the reason why I think this is bizarre is that for the class in my example `A a = { };` and `A a; a = { };` are not equivalent.

Comment: @SU3 Hmm, yes, `A a = { };` yields default constructor being called. Initialization uses different rules with assignment.